# How to force Nix to “install packages” by building them locally instead of downloading a pre-built binary?

Tags: nixos, nix

By "*install packages*" I mean to evaluate Nix build expressions (using `nix-env`, `nix-shell -p`, etc.) to build from source instead of using a [substitute](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#gloss-substitute).

<sup>Originally [posted on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175268/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl) but [Charles Duffy pointed it out][3] that it is more fitting to be here if itss about command-line tools or configuration. Still leaving it there because I assume forcing a package to always compile from source is possible by using the Nix language itself, I just don't yet know how. (Or if it is in fact not possible, someone will point it out, and then this question does belong here.)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Either set the [`substitute` option](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#conf-substitute) to `false` in [`nix.conf`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-conf-file) (the default is `true`) or use `--option substitute false` when invoking a Nix command.

```
nix-env --options substitute false -i hello

nix-shell --options substitute false -p hello
```

---

### Might not be the droids you are looking for

As Robert Hensing ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175268/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl#comment-117002657), [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228653/why-ignore-substitute)), Henri Menke ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175268/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl#comments-66175269)), and Vladimír Čunát ([comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634137/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl#comments-634138))  pointed out, this may not be the thing that you are really after.

To elaborate: I have been using the most basic Nix features confidently, but got to a point where I need to maintain and deploy a custom fork of a large application written in C, which is quite intimidating at the outset.

Tried to attack the problem the simplest way to just [fetch](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#chap-pkgs-fetchers) my fork and re-build it with the new source, so I boiled it down to this question. Although, I suspect that the right direction for me is something along the lines of [Nixpkgs/Create and debug packages](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nixpkgs/Create_and_debug_packages) in the [NixOS Wiki](https://nixos.wiki/).

#### Only re-build the package itself

[Vladimír Čunát commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634137/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl#comments-634138) that "*disabling substitutes makes you rebuild everything that's missing locally, even though I suspect that people asking such a question often only want to rebuild the specified package itself.*"

(This is probably achieved with [`nix-build`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-nix-build) or "just" overriding the original package but  could be wrong. The latter is mention (maybe demonstrated even?) in the NixOS wiki article [Development environment with `nix-shell`](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell) but haven't been able to read it thoroughly yet.)

#### Test for reproducibility

One might arrive to formulating this same question if they want to make sure that subsequent builds are deterministic. As [Henri Menke comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175268/how-to-force-nix-to-install-packages-by-building-them-locally-instead-of-downl#comments-66175269), one should use `nix-build --check` for that.

The `--check` option is easy to miss; it's not documented in [`man nix-build`](https://www.mankier.com/1/nix-build) or at [`nix-build`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-nix-build) in the [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable), but at `nix-store --realize` because (as [`man nix-build`](https://www.mankier.com/1/nix-build) explains it):

> `nix-build` is essentially a wrapper around `nix-instantiate` (to
> translate a high-level Nix expression to a low-level store derivation)
> and `nix-store --realise` (to build the store derivation) [and so] all
> options not listed here are passed to `nix-store --realise`, except
> for `--arg` and `--attr` / `-A` which are passed to `nix-instantiate`.

See detailed examples in the [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable) at [18.1.  Spot-Checking Build Determinism](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#idm140737321178144) and [the next section right after it](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#check-dirs-are-unregistered).

---

The relevant parts for the `substitute` configuration option under [the `nix.conf` section](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-conf-file) from the [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable):

> #### Name
>
> `nix.conf` — Nix configuration file
>
> #### Description
>
> Nix reads settings from two configuration files:
>
> - The system-wide configuration file `sysconfdir/nix/nix.conf` (i.e. `/etc/nix/nix.conf` on most systems), or `$NIX_CONF_DIR/nix.conf` if `NIX_CONF_DIR` is set.
> - The user configuration file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nix/nix.conf`, or `~/.config/nix/nix.conf` if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set.
>
> **You can override settings on the command line using the `--option` flag**,
> e.g. `--option keep-outputs false`.
>
> The following settings are currently available:
>
> [..]
>
> **substitute**
> If set to true (default), Nix will use binary substitutes if available. This option can be disabled to force building from source.

(Formerly known as `use-binary-caches`.)

---

**Notes**

Setting `substitute` to `false` (either with `--options` or in `nix.conf`) won't recompile the package if the command issue multiple times. That is, `hello` above would be compiled from source the first time, and then it will access the already present store path if the command issued again.

This is where it gets fuzzy: it is clear that no recompilation takes place because unless the package's Nix build expression doesn't change, the store output hash won't change either, making the next compilation output equivalent to the previous one, hence the action would be superfluous.

So if one would do some light hacking on a package, and just wanted to try it out locally (e.g., with `nix-shell`) then one would have to use `-I nixpkgs=a/local/nixpkgs/dir` to pick up those changes - and eventually do a recompilation? Or should one use `nix-build`?

See also question [How to `nix-build` again a built store path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486747/how-to-nix-build-again-a-built-store-path)

Comment: Note that disabling substitutes makes you rebuild *everything* that's missing locally, even though I suspect that people asking such a question often only want to rebuild the specified package itself.